# Unity find child with component in Start() function fails

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't find child objects of current gameobject(which is **Prefab**
I've got parent gameobject(it's creating from prefab in another script), and has 2 children. The hierarchy is like:

RewardItemPrefab

----RewardName(Has Text component).

----Image(Has SpriteRenderer component).

```
void Start ()
    {
        if (RewardText == null)
        {
            RewardText = this.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
            if (RewardText == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("RewardText == null");
                return;
            }
        }

        RewardText.text = _text;

        if (RewardImage == null)
        {
            RewardImage = this.GetComponentInChildren<Image>();
            if (RewardImage == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("RewardImage == null");
                return;
            }
        }

        RewardImage.sprite = Reward.LoadRewardSprite(RewardImageProp);
    }
```

But before this, as I said, this gameobject is created from another script:

```
var go = new GameObject(reward.Name, typeof(RewardProfileView));

go.GetComponent<RewardProfileView>().RewardItem = reward;
```

The 'RewardItem' property is Reward class property:

```
    public Reward RewardItem
    {
        get { return _reward; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                _reward = value;

                RewardTextProp = _reward.Name;

                RewardImageProp = _reward.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                _reward = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

RewardTextProp and RewardImageProp are just string fields.

NOTE: Need to make ability to set children properties of dynamicaly created prefab item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the **GameObject** in one `Start()` method, and then try to to access it in another `Start()` method, you will run into trouble. This is a classic example of a **race condition**, in which you do not know which `Start()` method will be executed first.

The easiest and the most straight forward solution is to put the **GameObject** creation part in an `Awake()` method.

The `Awake()` methods are guaranteed to run for all GameObjects before the `Start()` methods begin to run.